# how to pick a lower brightness monitor

Tags: display, brightness

on my monitor now I'm on 0% brightness and during the day it's ok for me, but at night is much too bright, and **I don't know at what specs to look at when buying a new monitor that will be able to get much lower brightness**.

---

I switched from a sony vaio laptop with TN screen to a MVA monitor (Benq EW2430)
and 0% brightness is ok for me during the day, but sometimes, evening/night I need it much lower brightness. I'm trying to pick a new monitor but I don't know how to choose one so that it would be able to provide a much lower brightness lower boundary.

**please note:** 
I can change the brightness in the video card settings but it's not the same as actually lowering monitor brightness, I would prefer to buy a new monitor

Comment: Looks like a nice monitor, I like it, have you tried adjusting other settings, like the Gamma and/or contrast? Gamma can bring down the brightness also. Contrast is usually for shadows, etc., but can also bring down the brightness.

Comment: You might want to try also, StackExchange's "Hardware Recommendations" https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are few websites that actually show the minimum brightness of a monitor. One I know is https://nl.hardware.info/monitoren.8 (Dutch). Sadly you can't filter for minimum brightness but when they have a review it's there. Check for "Minimale helderheid wit" under "Schermmetingen standaardweergave 2022".

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not adjust the brightness of your monitor but the brightness in your room which reduces eye strain. Just activate an **indirect warm light** when it gets darker.
2. To further reduce eye strain, you could try out [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) which adjusts the monitors color temperature automatically due to the local daylight and is even able to adjust your room lights accordingly (with a Philips Hue system).
3. Besides hardware recommendations (for which the brightness alone is not sufficient) you could also install a **glare reduction filter** in front of your monitor panel.

Comment: well, at night it is completely dark, and I'm using the monitor as a TV, but it is much too bright, it lights up the room

Comment: While these are valid recommendations, they are not reducing brightness. There are monitors that can use techniques to reduce the brightness beyond the minimum brightness of other monitors.